# How to change or disable the rendered size for WooCommerce images

Tags: css, wordpress, image, woocommerce

I have a problem in WooCommerce with the images that I upload. They have a poor quality, so I want to disable or change the rendering size.

[image]

I tried to change the setting in WooCommerce and WordPress option and theme, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Theme developers can alter how these images render.

To set them to different sizes yourself, there is this built-in way in the Customizer by going to Appearance > Customize > WooCommerce > Product Images.

Note that if you change your default values, your existing products' thumbnails, will need to be regenerated, so they exist with your new sizes. WooCommerce should take care of that automatically, but depending on the number of products and images on the site, it can take a while to process them all.

Official doc with further info https://woocommerce.com/document/image-sizes-theme-developers/#section-2